# Creating Linq Expressions using generic function

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I have a class (entity) like the following:

```
Public Class Product

    Property ID As Integer
    Property Name As String
    Property IssueDate As Date
    Property ExpireDate As Date
    Property NextCheckDate As Date

End Class
```

I am using Entity Framework 5 and I want to query my database using some predicates in the *where* clause. In order to create a predicate for dates I want to use a function like the following:

```
Function GetDateIssuePredicate(fromDate As Date?, toDate As Date?) As Expression(Of Func(Of Product, Boolean))

    Dim predicate As Expressions.Expression(Of Func(Of Product, Boolean))

    If fromDate.hasValue AndAlso toDate.hasValue Then
        predicate = (Function(p) p.IssueDate >= fromDate.Value AndAlso p.IssueDate<= toDate.Value)
    ElseIf fromDate.hasValue Then
        predicate = (Function(p) p.IssueDate >= fromDate.Value)
    ElseIf toDate.hasValue Then
        predicate = (Function(p) p.IssueDate<= toDate.Value)
    End If

    Return predicate

End Function
```

This function works for the specific entity field **IssueDate**. I want to avoid creating more functions doing exactly the same thing just for different entity fields (i.e.**ExpireDate**, **NextCheckDate**). Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: See [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

Comment: Wouldn't a predicate return a `Boolean`?

Comment: So, be an `Expression(Of Func(Of DateTime?, Boolean))`?

Comment: You are right! It should return a Boolean

Answer (score 0):

You could make it a function of DateTime rather than a function of Product.

```
Function GetDateIssuePredicate(fromDate As Date?, toDate As Date?) As Expression(Of Func(Of DateTime, DateTime)) 

    Dim predicate As Expressions.Expression(Of Func(Of DateTime, DateTime)) 

    If fromDate.hasValue AndAlso toDate.hasValue Then 
        predicate = (Function(d) d >= fromDate.Value AndAlso d <= toDate.Value) 
    ElseIf fromDate.hasValue Then 
        predicate = (Function(d) d >= fromDate.Value) 
    ElseIf toDate.hasValue Then 
        predicate = (Function(d) d <= toDate.Value) 
    End If 

    Return predicate 

End Function
```